# Can't get mottie jQuery keyboard work on popup box

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make work mottie jquery keyboard on a popup window. The keyboard works as expected in main page but doesn't appear on the popup. I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong but cannot figure it out.

Main page is like this

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#key').keyboard()
});
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">

            <div id="example" class="k-content">

    <div id="scheduler"><a href="test.php">
<button role="button">CONFERMA</button></a><input type="text" id="key">
```

Here, the keyboard is working correctly in the input #key

I cannot focus the keyboard here:

```
<div data-container-for="title" class="k-edit-field"><input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="title" title="Ospite" required="required" data-bind="value:title"></div>
```

Tried to use the class "k-input k-textbox" (each one, both) but keyboard not work. Could be a problem of script path?

Working code

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#key').keyboard()
});
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">

            <div id="example" class="k-content">

    <div id="scheduler"><a href="test.php">
<button role="button">CONFERMA</button></a><input type="text" id="key">
```

Not working code

```
<div data-container-for="title" class="k-edit-field"><input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="title" title="Ospite" required="required" data-bind="value:title"></div>
```

No errors, just the keyboard not appear.

Comment: Same situation if i set this way:
<script>
$(function(){
$('input').keyboard()
});
</script>
Works in the main page, not in the popup form

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, not sure why but i got the keyboard with a button:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("k-textbox");

  $('.k-textbox').keyboard()
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" style="float:right;">ASSEGNA</button>
```

If i press the button it works